# QGIS categorised layer style import

Tags: qgis, qml, style-manager

Is there a way of importing categorised layer styles into style-manager? I have created a set of styles for certain layers based on attribute data, but am having to go via properties>styles>load style> then save as default. It would be extremely useful to be able to load default style types based on layer naming like in the smart styles, but i believe this only works for styles with single symbols.